# I would like to move windows with ctrl+alt+numpad like before on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: numpad

I used to use a lot ctrl+alt+numpad to move windows, how can I use this feature on ubuntu 18 like it was default before?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the Gnome Extension Put Windows.

[image]

Press the left <kbd>Win</kbd> key and on the Numberpad 7/9/1/3 to place the active window in the upper left/upper right/lower left and lower right respectively.

You can install Gnome Extensions by following the instructions in this reference: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Thanks! Done! ;)

Comment: Perhaps you might also consider upvoting my answer? Thanks.